# How to add a new version of jar into the Clear Case Source Control

Tags: clearcase

I am trying to upgrade the commons-lang-2.0.jar to commons-lang-2.4.jar. When trying to add the 2.4 jar to the source control Clear Case is throwing the following error:

```
An element with this name (commons-lang-2.4.jar) has ALREADY been created in ClearCase for
this directory [lib], may be in a different version history of this directory that the one
you are seeing.
Review the version history of this directory [lib] to find it.
```

I feel this is because commons-lang-2.0 jar is existing in the lib folder and before adding 2.4 i need to remove 2.0. Can someone tell me if I am right? If so How can i remove 2.0 jar and replace it with 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a warning about "**evil twins**", in which your file `commons-lang-2.4.jar` was added, then removed from lib (and you would add it again, creating a new element with the same name, but a completely separate history: evil twin)
See also "[Evil twin problem and subtractive merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636712/evil-twin-problem-and-subtractive-merge)".

See "[About Evil twin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21125072)" to try and find which version of `lib` already contains your file `commons-lang-2.4.jar`.

Once you have found the right version of `lib`, you can merge it to your current version of lib, restoring the deleted `commons-lang-2.4.jar`.