# Clearcase - rebase operation was successful, but the files did not get copied

Tags: clearcase, rebase

I did a rebase yesterday with parent stream, when I did a folder compare with all the files in both parent and child stream I see 32 changes. That includes the changes which I had delivered to parent stream from a different child stream

This is what I did:

1. Delivered code to "`Int`" Stream from Stream `B`
2. Baselined "`Int`" Stream and then recommened that baseline
3. rebased Stream `A`

Below is my stream structure:

```
Int -> A
    -> B
```

I am not sure how I pull the changes again from Int again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure how I pull the changes again from Int again

You A should have everything it needs from `Int`.
If you need `B` to get those changes from `Int` (delivered "from a different child stream"), you can also rebase `B`, like you did `A`.

If the issue is:

- changes exist in `Int`
- `A` doesn't reflect those changes after rebase

Then display a version tree of the parent folder of those changes (both in the source and in the destination view): you might see some clue as to why the versions of the elements in that folder wasn't merged.

For instance, check that parent folder doesn't have an **[evil twin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1636712/6309)** in both branches.
If that were the case,  you would need to restore the proper content of that folder in Int, before rebasing again `A` (and even `B`).

---

If the issue is:

- changes exist in `Int`
- **`B`** doesn't reflect those changes after rebase
- You cannot rebase from `Int` to `B`

You need to:

- make a dummy change on `Int`
- put a new baseline on `Int`
- rebase that baseline on `B`

Comment: VonC, yes the issue is that changes exist in Int and dont in Stream B even after rebase. now it wont let me rebase second time. I see there is a different version in both Int and Stream B but I am still clueless. Would I be able to pull the changes again from int stream? if so how can I do it

Comment: @bhagyesh.shah ok, I have updated my answer to address the issue for B.