# Implementing changeset in base Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

What is the best way to this? Using labels? Using branches? It's highly unlikely we will get UCM on this project, and our build keeps on breaking, due to our sharing of branches for different purposes(I know, it's bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There  is no change set in Base ClearCase. It only exists (without counting UCM) in:

- Base ClearCase-ClearQuest (as mentioned in "[About Rational ClearCase triggers, change sets, and request sets](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_about_trig_cset_rset.htm)").
- [Base ClearCase integrated with RTC](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21641361)

Using branches to report specific changes remain the best way to get back to a stable state.

With CCRC (or ClearTeam), you have the notion of [pending changes](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_pending_changes_config_base.htm), in order to define how you will apply your current changes (including the option to integrate said changes in a new branch).

Comment: Something just occurred to me...How do you "roll back" changes(like a change set) though when using a branch for this purpose?

Comment: @wizurd through a "negative merge" or "subtractive merge": http://stackoverflow.com/a/1637405/6309